# Angular Routing - showing page not found

Tags: angularjs

// Hi I am trying to learn Angular Routing. I am just trying a simple example from youtube. When I click on page 1 and page 2 link. I still stay on the same page. Please help

```
//This is index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
    <head>
            <title>Angular Practice</title>[enter image description here][1]

            <script src = "app.js" type = "text/javascript"> </script>
    </head>

 <body>

<h1>This is Index.html page</h1> <br/>
<a href = "/#/page1"> This is page 1 </a> <br/>
<a href = "/#/page2"> This is page 2 </a> <br/>


<div ng-view> </div> 

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"> </script>

 </body>

</html>
```

// This is app.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
          $routeProvider.when('/page1', { templateUrl : 'partials/page1'});
          $routeProvider.when('/page1', { templateUrl : 'partials/page1'});
          $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo : 'index.html'});

          $locationProvider.html5mode({enabled : true, requiredBase : false});
    }]);
```

//this is page1.html

## This is page1

//this is page2.html

## This is page2

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuleO.png
```

Comment: Try remove `#` from link. like this `<a href = "/page2"> This is page 2 </a>`

Answer (score 0):

remove `#` from link. like this `<a href = "/page2"> This is page 2 </a>` becaused you enable `html5mode`

***Edit***

you should change `<html ng-app>` to `<html ng-app="myApp">`

Comment: Still it says page not found. github.com/shailuk/routingPrac.git this is the github link. PLEASE go thru it and let me know where am going wrong

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined at app.js:1. This is the error that i get when i check developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

By adding to @HJz suggestion.

In app.js you defined path for **page1** in both the conditions change one of them to **page2** with respective templateUrl

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
      $routeProvider.when('/page1', { templateUrl : 'partials/page1.html'});
      $routeProvider.when('/page2', { templateUrl : 'partials/page2.html'});
      $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo : 'index.html'});

      $locationProvider.html5mode({enabled : true, requiredBase : false});
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, update your html code as

```
<a href = "#page1"> This is page 1 </a> <br/>
```

Second, remove one of the **$routeProvider for /page1**, as the line has been dublicated

```
$routeProvider.when('/page1', { templateUrl : 'partials/page1'});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many syntactial errors in your code.....which i will describe in below explanation.

**Firstly** for the templateUrl attribute the template should be given along with its file extension.Assuming you are using a `.html` file as a template the TemplateUrl should be changed as below:

```
$routeProvider.when('/page1', { templateUrl : 'partials/page1.html'});
$routeProvider.when('/page2', { templateUrl : 'partials/page2.html'});
```

**The Second** syntactical error that u made is when using the html5Mode.Remember that html5Mode keyword function is case senstive.

change from `html5mode` to `html5Mode`

**Third** one is to change the requiredBase attribute to requireBase

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled : true, requireBase : false});
```

**Last** one is to remove the hasbang in the anchor tags to follow through the link.This is to be done to because you have enabled html5Mode.

```
<a href="/page1">This is page 1 </a>
  <br />
 <a href="/page2">This is page 2 </a>
  <br />
```

**EDIT 1:**

Also load your tags above the app.js  in head section as follows

```
<head>
  <title>Angular Practice</title>[enter image description here][1]
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"> </script>
  <script src = "app.js" type = "text/javascript"> </script>
```

But it is a good practice to load all scripts in the body tag .Just to highlight to the order of scripts i have put the scripts in head tag.

Comment: Still it says page not found. https://github.com/shailuk/routingPrac.git this is the github link. PLEASE go thru it and let me know where am going wrong

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at app.js:1. This is the error that i get when i check developer tools.

Comment: You are loading angular.js and route.js at a wrong place .Take both of the script tags above the app.js where you have loaded in head section

Comment: @shailuk Good to hear. IF you feel that this is answer, mark this as an answer and upvote it ; by clicking tick and up arrow button so that it would be helpful for other stoo